# Pack contents of subfolder using nuget

Tags: nuget

I've got a project I want to turn into a nuget package. The folder structure looks like this:

```
build/
     /stuff
          /Iwant
     /topack
stuffidontwantto.pack
mynuspec.nuspec
```

I want to pack everything under the build folder except for the build folder itself.

In the end I want the root of my package to look like this:

```
/stuff
    /Iwant
/topack
```

I'm doing this right now:

```
<files>
    <file src="build/**/**" />
</files>
```

Except when I create the package, the build folder is included.

How do I get just the contents of the build folder?

Comment: Figured it out, this question has the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041052/copy-files-from-a-subfolder-to-root-in-nuspec